# What is the Winter Bash?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Just logged on to the site, and I noticed a curious new link at the top of the page.  What does it mean?

Answer (score 2):

And if you want to wear a hat, go to your user profile, click on the hats link below your other user info (under the helpful flag counter), and select a hat from the popup.

Answer (score 1):

It means, it's time for HATS!

The [Winter Bash](http://winterba.sh/) is a promotion, where doing common tasks throughout the community can earn you special gifts. It you click the Winter Bash link at the top of the page.

[image]

A popup window will open, which lets you view all the hats you've earned.

[image]

From here you can click the [Winter Bash](http://winterba.sh/) link, which will take you to a page where you can learn more about how to earn hats.

If you don't like, don't want to look at, or just plain can't stomach hats. Clicking the *i hate hats* link will make known your hatred of hats, and you will not have to see them ever again (at least not on a StackExchange site).

So get out there asking, answering, voting on, and reviewing questions.  See how many hats you can earn.

## To Wear A Hat

Once you've earned a hat, or 5.  You can wear the hat proudly upon your Gravatar, simply by selecting it from your user profile page.

During Winter Bash, you'll notice a new item in the *stats* area of your user profile labeled *Hats*.

[image: User Profile Stats]

Once you have a hat, click the link and a dialog will open.

[image: Hat Selection Dialog]

Simply select the hat you'd like to wear, and close the dialog.  You'll notice (usually after a refresh), that your Gravatar is now sporting the new hat.

Good luck, and may the hats be with you.

For more information, check out the official [StackExchange Blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/12/welcome-to-winter-bash-2012/) article.